# How to add widget from activity? android 

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I'm looking for a way to add a widget that accompanies the main app in a single apk,

I managed to display widget picker menu via AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK and the intent class, however whenever I picked any widget, the menu just simply closed itself, and the widget  was not added to the homescreen.

What are steps that i need to take in order to add a widget from my app to the homescreen?

And my app is just a normal app, it's not a launcher app or homescreen

Answer (score 0):

> What are steps that i need to take in order to add a widget from my app to the homescreen?

The user does this, using the home screen. You do not. You do not have the right to force your app widget upon the users.

Comment: But the app pops up  a standard menu with list of widgets, so the user can choose the widget of his choice(not only mine) but in this case it does nothing.

Comment: Is AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK only usable in launcher type app?